# Record Audio From wireless Headset and Play it Through Bluetooth speaker

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

Record audio from BT headset. After record, switch route and play through wireless BT speaker.

I have implemented but audio is recording and playing in same headset or speaker. How record and play viseversa? any solution?

Comment: can you please declare your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hey @Rushi i think this code will help you for playing audio viseversa

```
    -(IBAction)RecordButtonPlayed:(id)sender
{
    if(player.playing)
    {
        [player stop];
    }

    if (!recorder.recording)
    {
        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:NULL];
        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth error:NULL];

         [_btnRecord setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"player-stop-outline-512.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [recorder record];
    }

    else
    {
         [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:NULL];

         [_btnRecord setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"171.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         [recorder stop];

    }
}
```

Comment: Superb...But only working with Manually set of Bluetooth headset and Speaker

Answer (score 2):

`AVAudioSession` can be used to set the default output port for your session.

The first thing to do is set up the category `AVAudioSession`. There are a couple of options here, since we want to be able to play and record sounds.

`AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` — Playback and record. The input and output need not occur simultaneously, but can if needed. Use for audio chat apps.

`AVAudioSessionCategoryMultiRoute` — Playback and record. Allow simultaneous input and output for different audio streams, for example, USB and headphone output. A DJ app would benefit from using the multiroute category. A DJ often needs to listen to one track of music while another track is playing. Using the multiroute category, a DJ app can play future tracks through the headphones while the current track is played for the dancers.

In this situation, it looks like `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` would be appropriate. Set it like this:

```
NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
BOOL success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]
                setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
                      error: &setCategoryError];

if (!success) { /* handle the error in setCategoryError */ }
```

Apple suggests setting the category once, and then modifying the input routes depending on our needs.

Once the category is set to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, the line below will return a list of available input and output routes.

```
NSArray <AVAudioSessionPortDescription *> *availableInputs = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance].availableInputs;
```

From the OP, this port is going to be used for recording.

`AVAudioSessionPortBluetoothHFP` - A Bluetooth enabled device supporting the Hands-Free Profile (HFP).

Set it like so:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setPreferredInput:AVAudioSessionPortBluetoothHFP error: &error];
```

Once recording is done, another device from the list of `availableInputs` can be picked for playback. Most probably, the playback port for BT speakers would be `AVAudioSessionPortBluetoothA2DP`, but [here is a comprehensive list of all playback ports](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSessionPortDescription_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Output_Port_Types).

Set it like so:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setPreferredInput:AVAudioSessionPortBluetoothA2DP error: &error];
```

Now the sound should play to the BT speaker.

It's important to note here that, `[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:&error];` will revert to the phone's internal speaker, and NOT the BT speaker.

Comment: i tried this already.but my problem is for output in BT speaker not default iphone speaker.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the OP. I though you wanted to play to the BT speaker. I'll edit my answer in the morning to show to how play to the iPhone speaker instead.

Comment: i want output in BT speaker not in iphone Speaker, i think you need to sleep.

Comment: Use this one AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth

Comment: You were right about the sleep @Rushi. I'll update my post with some more details about the BT setup on iOS, since it can be quite confusing. I'll start a bit further back and give you some options on what you can do. Let me know, again in the comments if something isn't clear.

Comment: Hi Vel. I'm confused with something. You call setPrefererredInput(:_), passing in bluetooth headphones, but then you call the same method, passing in a bluetooth speaker. Shouldn't the speaker be passed to some sort of "set output" method?

Answer (score 1):

Please use  AVAudioSession method.

```css
- (BOOL)setCategory:(NSString *)category 
        withOptions:(AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions)options 
              error:(NSError **)outError
```

and set the following 
with **category** as
AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
or AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord

and **options** as
***AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth***

Remember it may work for **A2DP** bluetooth only.
Try then with this 
*AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth*

Answer (score 1):

In order to receive bluetooth accessory events you would have to write below code in your view controller:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

[self becomeFirstResponder];
```

and then I think setting the Audio Session Category to MultiRoute could allow for audio to be routed separately.Whereas I tried to do so earlier in iOS7. and it seems that every time you change either the input or output, iOS changes the audio device altogether.I am not sure if its possible with new versions too.
However you can get the list of all currently available inputs using following code:

```
// portDesc.portType could be for example - BluetoothHFP, MicrophoneBuiltIn, MicrophoneWired
NSArray *availInputs = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] availableInputs];
int count = [availInputs count];
for (int k = 0; k < count; k++) {
    AVAudioSessionPortDescription *portDesc = [availInputs objectAtIndex:k];
    NSLog(@"input%i port type %@", k+1, portDesc.portType);
    NSLog(@"input%i port name %@", k+1, portDesc.portName);
}
```

and outputs as:

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
NSLog(@"Outputs: %@", [[session currentRoute] outputs]);
```

Good Luck!!